# Inateck BTA-CSR4B2 USB Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter not scanning

Tags: bluetooth

I bought an Inateck BTA-CSR4B2 USB Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter and plugged it into my Raspberry Pi. Setup was smooth (got bluetooth, blueman, bluez-utils from apt-get), but I can't get any scan results from or to the device. That is:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ hcitool scan
Scanning ...
```

and that hangs forever giving no results. I also cannot see my device when scanning for devices on my phone, even though the device's visibility is on (set from menu->preferences->bluetooth manager).

Details of my hardware:

From lsusb:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

From hciconfig:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:15:83:6B:DC:EC  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN INQUIRY 
    RX bytes:16536 acl:0 sco:0 events:4651 errors:0
    TX bytes:1406 acl:0 sco:0 commands:84 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
Can't read local name on hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

From dmesg:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[    6.543365] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[    6.922028] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.067461] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.192414] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.351435] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   28.146691] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   28.146728] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   28.146786] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   28.199895] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   28.199988] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   28.200007] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1363.335848] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x040c tx timeout
[405706.120334] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[405716.130735] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c1a tx timeout
[406387.459174] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c24 tx timeout
[406395.789452] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0401 tx timeout
[406518.564709] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0402 tx timeout
[406774.345477] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0401 tx timeout
[406899.800765] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0402 tx timeout
[407131.450523] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c14 tx timeout
[407585.369650] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c14 tx timeout
```